# How to add a style to a particular column in EXTjs Editor Grid Panel which has column vars?

Tags: javascript, extjs

/*
Need to have pointer cursor only on the particular column instead for whole grid or the row.

*/

```js
this.testRenderer = function(v, m, r, ri, ci, ds) {
 var total = formatMoney(r.data["total"], cur);
 return total;
};

var columnsVar = [
 {
 header: getMsg('test', 'testp'),
 dataIndex: 'test.name',
 sortable: true
 },
 {
 header: getMsg('test', 'testtotal'),
 sortable: true,
 dataIndex: 'total',
 editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
 allowBlank: false,
 maxLength: 48
 }),
 render:this. testRenderer

 }, {
 header: getMsg('test', 'active'),
 sortable: true,
 dataIndex: 'test.Status'
 }
];


this.testGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
 title:getMsg('test','Details'),
 flex: 3,
 cls: 'cnqr-shuttle-grid',
 border: false,
 header: true,
 clicksToEdit: 1,
 enableHdMenu: false,
 enableColumnHide: false,
 enableColumnMove: false,
 autoHeight: true,
 viewConfig: {
     getRowClass : function(record, rowIndex, p, store) {
      p.tstyle = ' cursor: pointer;'
     },
     forceFit: true,
     scrollOffset: 0 // the grid will never have scrollbars
 },
 tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
     ctCls: 'grayButtonToolBar  border-toolbar'
 }),
 store: store1,
 selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel(),
 columns: columnsVar

});
```

//testGrid is the Ext editor grid and column vars has 3 columns and I need have pointer cursor only on the 2nd column testtotal col. Have tried adding code at the testRenderer and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

On the column you want the pointer on, add the following:

```
renderer: function(value, metadata) {
    metadata.tdCls = 'pointer-only';
    return value;
}
```

And in your CSS add the class:

```
.pointer-only {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tk1) illustrating this on the last column of a simple grid

Comment: I am not allowed to use the CSS, have access only to EXT JS file.

Comment: Thank you so much :-)  I added the renderer function in my column and it started working. You saved my day.                                                                       renderer: function (value, metadata) {
                                metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;';
                                return value;
                            }

Comment: Thank you so much. I added the logic suggested by you and it started working. 

renderer: function (value, metadata) {
 metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;';
 return value;
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
renderer: function (value, metadata) {
 metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;';
 return value;
}
```